# Ansible : compass-core missing in gem list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ansible, compass

I face an issue with a grunt build so I check the version of compass (`compass -v`) and the same message happen :

```
stderr: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find compass-core (~> 1.0.2) amongst [compass-1.0.3, sass-3.4.18] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:777:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
```

I've provide my server with ansible and I've already checked that sass :

```
Sass 3.4.18 (Selective Steve)
```

Does anyone know how to debug this ?

---

EDIT

The fact is I was using an old way to install sass and compass.
After uninstalling and replaying the task ansible, I saw that only root has the gem installed.

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


$ sudo gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.3.4)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.10)
multi_json (1.11.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
sass (3.4.18)
```

So my question has change : How to install gem for a specific user or for all the user with ansible ?

Here my ansible script :

```
  - name: Install ruby gems as Grunt dependencies
    gem: name="{{ item }}" state=present include_dependencies=yes user_install=yes
    with_items:
      - sass
      - compass
```

the include_depencies and user_install are optional flags

Comment: `gem install compass-core`

Comment: @mudasobwa, does compass-core has to be install to use compass ?

Comment: Well, both the etymology of the word `core` and your error output suggest that.

Comment: Yes, sorry my question was : why compass-core isn't a dependency of compass ?
And when I execute sudo gem install compass, it should install compass-core, multi_json, compass-import-once ans so on ...

Comment: Please ask this question in `compass` mail-group/chat/irc/github-issues/whereever. I have nothing to do with compass maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the gem for a specific user you would need to run it in the context of the user, e.g.

```
  - name: Install ruby gems as Grunt dependencies
    gem: name="{{ item }}" state=present include_dependencies=yes user_install=yes
    with_items:
      - sass
      - compass
    become: yes
    become_user: someuser
```

To install it globally, set `user_install` to a falsy value:

```
  - name: Install ruby gems as Grunt dependencies
    gem: name="{{ item }}" state=present include_dependencies=yes user_install=no
    with_items:
      - sass
      - compass
    become: yes
    become_user: root
```

Comment: Thank you, the flag definition of the ansible gem module is "Install gem in user's local gems cache or for all users". My english isn't perfect but it isn't really clear, is it ?